# Is it advisable to use Arabic characters in naming s3 object?

Tags: amazon-s3

In my s3 bucket, will there be any problem in accessing object over the browser, if the objects are named in Arabic characters.

Answer (score 0):

See [Object key naming guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) for specifics and recommendations on what to avoid.

Theoretically:

> You can use any UTF-8 character in an object key name. However, using certain characters in key names can cause problems with some applications and protocols. The following guidelines help you maximize compliance with DNS, web-safe characters, XML parsers, and other APIs.